# Can't Type password in Sql Plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I recently install the oracle software, after completion of installation.
i tried to open the sql plus, 
there i typed my username and pressed enter
in next line, i am trying to type password, but my cursor is not moving, like it is not displaying anything, just blinking only.
then error  message is displayed.

Comment: It's normal behavior. It will not appear on the screen.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is not appearing and whenever i am trying, it shows an error, what can i do to resolve this problem

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could tell us what the error message says.

Comment: Ctrl-V doesn't work, i have a password like: cIAA9nFPGw5IFVIcw5FOxeWRFUIUOcv 
typing it over without any feedback is a bit hard!.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. This following command worked for me:

```
CONNECT SYSTEM/your password
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your issue?

From command prompt of your OS,

1. Type `sqlplus`
2. For pre-12c, just give `username`, press `enter`. On 12c, mention `username@pluggable database name`, else by default you would be connecting to `container database`.
3. Now enter `password`, you won't see anything, but when typed and entered correctly, you would `login` successfully.

Let's see in 12c,

My OS is `windows` so I just typed `sqlplus` in command prompt,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lkb>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Fri Oct 31 13:06:12 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: lalit@pdborcl
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Fri Oct 31 2014 13:02:03 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing opt
ions

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The password gets typed in after you enter the username but does not get displayed due to security purpose.